# how we count array values according to last column in php

Tags: php, arrays

below is my array .in this array all zero index values(outlook, temp, and play is headings)
and 1 to 5 index contain the values.
and last index 3 is my predictor.
now i want to count the Last index values yes or no according to 0 and 1 index.

```
$array1 = Array
(
        [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'Outlook'
            [1] => Sunny
            [2] => Sunny
            [3] => Overcast 
            [4] => Rainy
            [5] => Rainy
    )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'Temp'
            [1] => Hot
            [2] => Hot
            [3] => Hot
            [4] => Mild
            [5] => Cool
    )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'Play'
            [1] => No
            [2] => Yes
            [3] => Yes
            [4] => No
            [5] => Yes
    )
)
```

i wish output like below .
in which i count sunny containing 1 yes and 1 no and so on.

```
Array
(
    [Outlook] => Array
        (
            [Sunny] => Array
                (
                    [No] => 1
                    [Yes] => 1
                )

            [Overcast ] => Array
                (
                    [Yes] => 1
                )

            [Rainy] => Array
                (
                    [Yes] => 1
                    [No] => 1
                )          
        )

    [Temp] => Array
        (
            [Hot] => Array
                (
                    [No] => 1
                    [Yes] => 2
                )
            [Mild] => Array
                (
                    [Ni] => 1
                )

            [Cool] => Array
                (
                    [Yes] => 1
                )
        )
```

i have write code below but its not work properly

```
                $headingarray = array();
                $finalarrays = array();
                $last = "";
                $innerkey= "";
                foreach($array1 as $mapkey => $value){
                    $last = count($mapkey);

                    $headingarray = $mapedarray[$mapkey][0];

                    foreach($mapvalue as $mapckey => $mapcvalu){

                        $innerkey= count($mapckey);

                        for($i=0; $i<$last; $i++){


                        for($j=1; $j<count($innerkey); $j++){


                                $finalarray[$headingarray][$mapedarray[$i][$j]][$mapedarray[$last][$j]]++;
                            } 

                        }   

                    }
            }

                echo '<pre>';print_r($finalarrays);echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way I would do it. I would get the last array key, then looping over the full array, use that key to set your final array keys and values.

```
//go to the last array
end($array1);
//get the last array key
$last = key($array1);
//reset back to the start of the array
reset($array1);

//array to hold the final array
$finalarrays = array();

//loop over the full array
foreach($array1 as $key=>$v1){

    //if the last array, break out of the loop
    if($last==$key)break;
    else {
        //loop over each array values
        foreach($v1 as $k2=>$v2){
            //if the 1st, set the final array key
            if($k2==0){
                $finalarrays[$v2]=array();
                $currentKey=$v2;
            }
            else {
                //use the last array key value to set the final array keys and values
                $finalarrays[$currentKey][$v2][$array1[$last][$k2]] = isset($finalarrays[$currentKey][$v2][$array1[$last][$k2]]) ? $finalarrays[$currentKey][$v2][$array1[$last][$k2]]+1: 1;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

see it in action here - https://3v4l.org/EqgXJ